# Using only the last 12 Characters of a GUID / UUID?

Tags: filenames, guid

Here is the problem I want to solve:
Let's say I have a collection of 30 000 files (videos, images, sounds, etc...). And let's say I need to move/rename them a lot (including sub and parent folder). Not to mention those files will move from different OS (win, osx, linux(NAS) ) in a near future.

My problem stands when it comes to keep a link references to those files in my personal notes (evernote and blog mostly). Since URLs will broke all the time, I was thinking of adding a GUID/UUID in the file name (only for the file I need to refer to). this way, I could always do a search and find my file no matter where it is.

But GUID are quite a big string (36 characters if I've counted right). I don't need a world global uniqueness for my file. Just enough uniqueness to make a difference between maybe less than 10 000 reference (in my hole life ^^).

So I was thinking of using only the last 12 characters of a GUID string and add it to my file. Keeping the same string in my notes. And in case of collision, that would not be a problem because I know my files well and figuring out witch one is the right wouldn't be a problem.

Could this works?
Could I use an even smaller string ? (like the first 8 characters)

thx for your help.

Best.
William

Comment: Why not just give each file / item a unique reference? Start at 1.

Comment: Because, in my test, I've realized it was way faster to generate a GUID than keeping some kind of count. But it would work yhea. (I'm lasy ^^)

Answer (score 0):

```
files_array=( $(ls directory/of/files) )

for i in "${files_array[@]}"
do
  var=$(echo $(uuidgen -r | cut -d'-' -f 5))
  rn $i $i"$var"
done
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?